# CATiledLayer not lining up the "layers"

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I have a CATiledLayer in a scrollView.

The total image is 11,000 x 17,000 and I've cut that up in to tiles of 256 x 256.

When I'm in the zoomed in mode the `UIScrollview` works perfectly with the `CATiledLayer` and I can see them all flickering in to view and I can scroll to all edges of the photo.

However, I have a second level of detail which uses an image of size 1650 × 2550 which I have also cut up in to tiles of 256 x 256.

The problem I have is when I zoom out of the `UIScrollView` and the low res images take over the image is shifted and is surrounded by black to the bottom and right.  i.e. the scroll view content size is still the same size and the image being displayed is sitting really small in the top left corner.

Do I need to do something when the level of detail changes?

It is the first time I've used the `CATiledLayer` so I could have missed something.

::EDIT::

I know how to explain it better.  The low res tiles are being loaded and being drawn but they are being drawn at the same physical size as the high res tiles.

Comment: Check this example from Apple, it could be useful: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks.  However, I found the problem.  I didn't realise that the images have to go in halves all the way.  i.e. each detail layer has to be exactly half the size of the previous.  It's now working perfectly, thanks.